# How to do SEO for Real estate website

Tags: seo

Can anyone recommend some tips for the SEO of real estate website.The competition is really high so how to make your website an authority website to make it SEO friendly.

Comment: General questions about SEO are marked as a duplicate of the linked question. If you can edit the question to ask something more specific, then it will be added to the review queue for consideration to be reopened.

Answer (score -1):

1) do a competitive keyword analysis
2) select the keywords that would be appropriate for your website
3) Add keywords to the site
4) work on backlink generation for those keywrods...